# Vertical scrollpane problem in jdialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, vertical-scrolling

i have a question regarding the vertical scrollpane in jdialog.when i run My application the jdialog vertical scrollbar displays end of the data.I need to scroll it upwards.How can i get the scrollbar bydefault at the top.

Comment: are you meaning scroll to the left-top of JScrollPane

Comment: this is how my jdialog looks as soon as it runned.    http://www.sendspace.com/file/tlk92l

Comment: Please don't post links to documents with proprietary formats; consider using a free image hosting website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you scrolling? If a text component, oftentimes setting the caret to the top of the component works. Please have a look at Rob Camick's Swing tips blog for more on this: [Java Tips Weblog: Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/)

Comment: textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());this works for displaying scrollbar bottom of the dialog.What should i use to display it to top of the dialog.

Comment: @hemanth: Try `textArea.setCaretPosition(0);` I have not tried this, but it seems the obvious solution.

Comment: Read the call, and read the documentation : setCaretPosition(int position). If you pass the length of the document, it goes to the end. What could you imagine to pass to make it go to the beginning?

Comment: @hemanth: then you might wish to create a small compilable runnable program that demonstrates you problem, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), and post it in your question so we can test, alter and correct it.

Comment: got the result using this piece of code:    jTextArea1.select(0,0);

Comment: Now i have a question. I have a url in jtextarea i need to change the color of it.How can i achieve this.Html tags are not working..

Answer (score 4):

[JViewport#scrollRectToVisible()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)